# Add a font to a website

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, addition, truetype

I am trying to add this font : http://www.fonts2u.com/vps-dong-da-hoa.font

to my website. Here is my CSS :

```
@font-face {
font-family: "VPSDODAH";
src: url(http://localhost/blablabla/wp-content/plugins/buddypress/bp-themes/frisco-for-buddypress/VPSDODAH.ttf) format("truetype");}

#header h1 a {
font-family: "VPSDODAH";}
```

The URL to the font is correct but it's not working, what can it be ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: URL is localhost ? can't use Google Web Fonts?

Comment: you need to download all the other font types as well - not just the ttf.  Click on the @font-face button instead of the download button and it's best to use relative paths to the fonts

Comment: What browser are you running?  Some browsers might not process ttf fonts (IE, Im looking at you) using @font-face.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all browser support *.ttf*. Use a font generator to get all the font types ( I use [font2web](http://www.font2web.com/) ) and then just add the fonts via [@font-face](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-webfonts-20020802/):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'fontName';
    src: url('../fonts/fontName.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/fontName.eot?iefix') format('eot'),
         url('../fonts/fontName.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/fontName.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/fontName.svg#fontName') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
 }
```

Read here about [browser font support](http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/browser-fonts-support-comparison).

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) website for your web font generation. If your font exists, you can convert it and get all the @font-face parameters to apply it for your website.