# Font Face not working in IE8 as expected

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, font-face

I've used the following code to get a custom font in my website! using the following code!

```
@font-face{
     font-family:portagolTC;
     src: url(../font/PortagoITC_TT.woff?) format('woff');
     src: url(../font/PortagoITC_TT.eot?#iefix) format('opentype');
}
```

This works in chrome,ff,IE10,IE9 but not in IE8! What am I doing wrong here? Please correct me if I'm doing anything wrong.

Note : I've googled and found few stackoverflow answers but nothing seems to solve my problem.

```
CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error. 
PortagoITC_TT.woff
CSS3114: @font-face failed OpenType embedding permission check. Permission must be Installable. 
PortagoITC_TT.ttf
CSS3114: @font-face failed OpenType embedding permission check. Permission must be Installable. 
PortagoITC_TT.ttf
```

Comment: Possible duplicat [Add a font to a website](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16541871/1763929).

Comment: I checked this but it doesn't work!

Comment: Maybe it's due the font. Try with a different one for test.

Comment: When looking in the console output of the browser, do you have an error, something like: CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error. ?

Comment: I've updated the question with the errors!

Comment: Did you try my solution ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If IE8 throws the `CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error`, you probably have the *non-matching font-family name* problem.

To resolve this, you need to edit your font file, define identical names for Fontname, Family name and Name for humans and export your TTF. This can be done using the [FontForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fontforge/) application. Afterwards, you than again convert it for web (EOT, WOFF).

More info: http://fontface.codeandmore.com/blog/ie-7-8-error-with-eot-css3111/

**Update**

Made it working by downloading an own version of the TTF font and converted it for web. The CSS I used:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'portagoitc-tt';
    src: url('fonts/portagoitc-tt.eot');
    src: url('fonts/portagoitc-tt.eot?iefix') format('opentype'),
         url('fonts/portagoitc-tt.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/portagoitc-tt.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Just tried it locally and it is working on all browsers (including IE7 and IE8). I've download the 'PortagoITC TT' font TTF format and converted it for web. The CSS I used: 

&at;font-face {
    font-family: 'portagoitc-tt';
    src: url('fonts/portagoitc-tt.eot');
    src: url('fonts/portagoitc-tt.eot?iefix') format('opentype'),
         url('fonts/portagoitc-tt.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/portagoitc-tt.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

It seems to be a problem with your font files. Which tool did you use to convert?

Comment: If you could let me know where you downloaded the font and converted it, it might help me. and could you please add the CSS in your answer..

Comment: I've downloaded it from http://font.downloadatoz.com/font,108525,portagoitc-tt.html and coverted it using http://www.font2web.com/ Let me know if it works at your side.

Answer (score 3):

I had trouble with IE8 and had **no console error messages**. What solved my problem was to alter my `@font-face` code slightly:

**Before:**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Hero";
    src: local("Hero"),
         url("../fonts/Hero.eot?"),
         url("../fonts/Hero.woff") format("woff"),
         url("../fonts/Hero.ttf") format("truetype"),
         url("../fonts/Hero.svg#Hero") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

**After:**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Hero";
    src: url("../fonts/Hero.eot"); /* this line made the difference */
    src: local("Hero"),
         url("../fonts/Hero.eot?"),
         url("../fonts/Hero.woff") format("woff"),
         url("../fonts/Hero.ttf") format("truetype"),
         url("../fonts/Hero.svg#Hero") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Although my company bought the font, all formats (eot, woff etc), I didnt got it to work in IE8 and IE10. I uploaded the ttf format to http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator and got a 'webfont'?? version and now it works!!!

Should have watched the console sooner of IE, there is stated permiossion troubles.