# ie8 not rendering @font-face fonts on first page load or refresh

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

Here is the website in question: https://www.cocokeyorlando.com

IE8 is not rendering my custom font-faces when I first go to the page.  There are two font-faces that should be loading for the slider text. If I reload/refresh the page nothing changes.

However, when I click on the logo to go back to the homepage, they start working.

Here is the code I am using to load them.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'neoretrodrawregular';
    src: url('fonts/NEORD.eot');
    src: url('fonts/NEORD.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/NEORD___-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/NEORD___-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/NEORD___-webfont.svg#neoretrodrawregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'blackjackregular';
    src: url('fonts/black_jack.eot');
    src: url('fonts/black_jack.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/black_jack-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/black_jack-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/black_jack-webfont.svg#blackjackregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: None of the related questions over on the side help? `---->`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you fonts/black_jack.eot file is there, and the CSS is all correct.

The site is not rendering well in IE11, or in IE8 mode. The site works fine in Chrome.

Check out these...
[Font Face not working in IE8 as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151570/font-face-not-working-in-ie8-as-expected)