# Fonts are not working in IE

Tags: html, css, fonts

code :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'GothamRnd-Medium';
    src: url('about/fonts/GothamRnd-Medium/GothamRnd-Medium.eot');
    src: url('about/fonts/GothamRnd-Medium/GothamRnd-Medium.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('about/fonts/GothamRnd-Medium/GothamRnd-Medium.woff') format('woff'),
         url('about/fonts/GothamRnd-Medium/GothamRnd-Medium.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('about/fonts/GothamRnd-Medium/GothamRnd-Medium.svg#GothamRnd-Medium') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    }

    @font-face {
    font-family: 'ArcherBoldItalic';
    src: url('about/fonts/Archer-BoldItal/archer-boldital.eot');
    src: url('about/fonts/Archer-BoldItal/archer-boldital.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('about/fonts/Archer-BoldItal/archer-boldital.woff') format('woff'),
         url('about/fonts/Archer-BoldItal/archer-boldital.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('about/fonts/Archer-BoldItal/archer-boldital.svg#ArcherBoldItalic') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;     
    }


    @font-face {
    font-family: 'proxima_novalight';
    src: url('about/fonts/ProximaNova-Light/proximanova-light-webfont.eot');
    src: url('about/fonts/ProximaNova-Light/proximanova-light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('about/fonts/ProximaNova-Light/proximanova-light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('about/fonts/ProximaNova-Light/proximanova-light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('about/fonts/ProximaNova-Light/proximanova-light-webfont.svg#proxima_novalight') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

I have embedded three fonts. Out of three fonts 'proxima_novalight' font is working perfectly in IE8 but other two fonts are not working. I checked all the code but i didn't find the solution. Its working fine in other browsers. Any idea guys ?

Answer (score 2):

> If IE8 throws the CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error, you
>   probably have the non-matching font-family name problem.
>
> To resolve this, you need to edit your font file, define identical
>   names for Fontname, Family name and Name for humans and export your
>   TTF. This can be done using the FontForge application. Afterwards, you
>   than again convert it for web (EOT, WOFF).

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'portagoitc-tt';
    src: url('fonts/portagoitc-tt.eot');
    src: url('fonts/portagoitc-tt.eot?iefix') format('opentype'),
         url('fonts/portagoitc-tt.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/portagoitc-tt.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Please check for further details

[Font Face not working in IE8 as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151570/font-face-not-working-in-ie8-as-expected)

Comment: So what? you can upload it or give us fiddle