# Font-face won't load on IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, font-face

I've tried many of the solutions found in other topics but still the font won't load in IE8.
The fonts are converted by FontSquirrel and also the CSS has been generated there. No alternation.
According to the other topics.. it should work now. But.. it does not. Is there any workaround to make it work? Or is it just one of those things i can keep hating ie8 about?

Problem can be seen on this URL: [www.kokomogroningen.nl](http://www.kokomogroningen.nl)

Font-face is currently:

```
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'dincondregularregularcondRgRgularregularcondRgRgularregularcondRgRg';
        src: url('/css/ff_din_condensed_regular-webfont.eot');
        src: url('/css/ff_din_condensed_regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('/css/ff_din_condensed_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
             url('/css/ff_din_condensed_regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
             url('/css/ff_din_condensed_regular-webfont.svg#dincondregularregularcondRgRgularregularcondRgRgularregularcondRgRg') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }
```

Comment: please post relevant code here and not just link to your site

Answer (score 0):

Source http://css-tricks.com/

```
  @font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
   src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
   url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
   url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
   url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

This may also help

[Font Face not working in IE8 as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151570/font-face-not-working-in-ie8-as-expected)

Comment: Thx, but the css trick you hand out is already what i'm using.