# Myriad pro font is not shown properly

Tags: css

I have used myriad pro font in my website and this font is uploaded on server and i have given link for this font as below

```
@font-face{
    font-family: "Myriad-Pro";  
    src: url(http://www.anaveer.in/honda/font/MYRIADPRO-REGULAR.OTF) format("truetype");
}
```

but still this font is not show, is there any another way of solution for this problem?

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16541871/1763929).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add a font to a website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541436/add-a-font-to-a-website)

Answer (score 0):

I have tested on my local machine. the browser is chrome.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
@font-face{
    font-family: "Myriad-Pro";  
    src: url(http://www.anaveer.in/honda/font/MYRIADPRO-REGULAR.OTF) format("truetype");
}
body{ font-family:Myriad-Pro; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
This should be in myriad-pro font
</body>
</html>
```

this worked perfectly. (I think the font is what I am pasting a screenshot).

[image: Just pasted your code and a static html]

Probably you may wish to let us know which browser is giving a hickup to you.
Either way, since you are uploading it to your server, I suggest you have a look at font-squirrel's all-type-fonts and their css generated for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check first that you have a legally valid license to use Myriad Pro on the Web. Then check the font vendor’s instructions on such use.

Specific things to note:

- IE does not support OTF for Web fonts, you need other formats.
- The font files should reside on the same server as the page using them, or else the server hosting them must allow cross-site use.