# I am using Myriad pro font family in my webpages and i put them online and give link as fontface as below. but this is not working

Tags: css

```
@font-face {
font-family: "Myriad-Pro";
src: url('http://anaveer.in/honda/font/MYRIADPRO-REGULAR.OTF');
src: url('http://anaveer.in/honda/font/MYRIADPRO-REGULAR.OTF')  format("opentype") ;
font-weight:normal;
font-style:normal;
}
```

is there any mistake in this code?
These fonts are not show on other PC where this fonts are not installed. I used this fonts in my website but not showing on other pc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Myriad pro font is not shown properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374053/myriad-pro-font-is-not-shown-properly)

Comment: Repeating your question in a slightly modified form is not constructive.

Answer (score 2):

Only OTF file won't help, you need to generate a web font kit and include respective files to make it work.

http://convertfonts.com/

Upload your OTF file and then download the font kit, copy the style you get in font kit to your css, use the font name properly for which you include the files.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your font to web-format (woff, eot, ttf etc.). Many web-sites do this online. Exemple http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator